R terra Flow Accumulation resulting raster with DN = 1
I encountered problems in calculating flow accumulation using terra::flowAccumulation() from lidar-based DEM. I've inspected the visual and general properties of the DEM and flow direction rasters, which result in seemingly no inherent problems.
print(Elev_Sumsel )
        class       : SpatRaster 
        dimensions  : 4150, 3118, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
        resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
        extent      : 385089.9, 416269.9, 9761254, 9802754  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
        coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S (EPSG:32748) 
        source      : Elev_10m.tif 
        name        :       Elev 
        min value   :  0.4904917 
        max value   : 38.2673874

print(fill_Sumsel )
        class       : SpatRaster 
        dimensions  : 4150, 3118, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
        resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
        extent      : 385089.9, 416269.9, 9761254, 9802754  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
        coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S (EPSG:32748) 
        source      : Filled_10m.tif 
        name        :     Filled 
        min value   :  0.6166557 
        max value   : 38.1634369 

print(fdsurf_Sumsel )
        class       : SpatRaster 
        dimensions  : 4150, 3118, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
        resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
        extent      : 385089.9, 416269.9, 9761254, 9802754  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
        coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S (EPSG:32748) 
        source      : FlowDirSurf_10m.tif 
        name        :   FlowDirSurf 
        min value   : -4.973005e-05 
        max value   :  7.517665e-02

visual inspection here


but when I performed flow accumulation, it resulted in a raster containing value = 1.
fasurf_Sumsel <- flowAccumulation(fdsurf_Sumsel)
print(fasurf_Sumsel )
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4150, 3118, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 385089.9, 416269.9, 9761254, 9802754  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S (EPSG:32748) 
source(s)   : memory
varname     : FlowDirSurf_10m 
name        : FlowDirSurf 
min value   :           1 
max value   :           1 
    


any idea what happen here?

According to ?terra::terrain(), flowdir is encoded as powers of 2 (0 to 7), hence as 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128. Your flowdir values already range between -4.973005e-05 and 7.517665e-02. So the issue does not seem to be with flowacc, but with flowdir already. How exactly do you fill the sinks?

so it indicates the slope gradient of my DEM is too low (flat terrain)?

I wouldn't say so... Maybe there are some memory allocation issues with terra, since we're dealing with a rather huge raster here, maybe this is about fill sinks. But since you do not provide neither code nor data, one can only guess.

After some (many) failed attempts, the issue can be resolved by running a more complex D-Infinity Accumulation algorithm using whitebox library (wbt_d_inf_flow_accumulation()). My first try failed but it indicates flat areas/pits over the DEM area.
Sumsel_Elev_surf<- wbt_d_inf_flow_accumulation( input = Sumsel_Elev_surf, 
                                                output = "E:/...../Topo/Sumsel_Flow_Acc_surf.tif")
**********************************************************************************
WARNING: Interior pit cells were found within the input DEM. It is likely that the 
            DEM needs to be processed to remove topographic depressions and flats prior to
            running this tool.
**********************************************************************************
d_inf_flow_accumulation - Elapsed Time (excluding I/O): 0.643s
Error: [==] Can only match character values if x is categorical

so, I re-run the fill and continued by D-inf flow accumulation.
whitebox::wbt_fill_depressions(dem = "E:/........./Topo/Elev_Sumsel_Fix.tif", output = "E:/KLHK/KHG/2_Sumsel/3_olah4/Topo/Elev_Sumsel_Filled.tif")
fill_depressions - Elapsed Time (excluding I/O): 0.194s
 
whitebox::wbt_d_inf_flow_accumulation(input = "E:/........./Topo/Elev_Sumsel_Filled.tif", output = "E:/........./Topo/Sumsel_Flow_Acc_surf_Filled.tif")
d_inf_flow_accumulation - Elapsed Time (excluding I/O): 0.640s

Sumsel_Flow_Acc_surf <- terra::rast("E:/........../Topo/Sumsel_Flow_Acc_surf.tif") 
print(Sumsel_Flow_Acc_surf)
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4149, 3115, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 385102.4, 416252.4, 9761257, 9802747  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S (EPSG:32748) 
source      : Sumsel_Flow_Acc_surf.tif 
name        : Sumsel_Flow_Acc_surf 

